# Getting full image url for products via REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, magento2, rest-api, http-request

After accessing the Rest API (http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products/SKU) to get the product details, the response is something like this:

> `{ "attribute_code": "image", "value": "/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg" }, { "attribute_code": "small_image", "value": "/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg" }, { "attribute_code": "thumbnail", "value": "/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg" }`

What should be the base url/prefix for the jpg in the `attribute_code` keys ?

Comment: have you tried : api/rest/products/sku/images?

Comment: this link does not work in magento 2.0

Comment: Magento 2 :  /V1/products/:sku/media

Comment: Check my answer.. all the api's in 2.0 will give you an incomplete URL.. you can hardcode the directory path.

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2x the product image urls are all relative.  It's possible some extension or usage of CDN could change the base path.  You can call the the V1/store/StoreConfigs api and use the baseMediaUrl value to get the full path.

Answer (score 3):

Found the URL on server directory. Just add a prefix to the URL.

Prefix: http://magento.com/pub/media/catalog/product/(url in API response)

Comment: This would be safe as long as no one has changed the **Base URL for User Media Files** value from Admin->Stores->General->Web.  (This was the point which [@Chuck](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/588/chuck) was making in the other answer.)