# Construct full image URL as REST API Client (for products and categories)

Tags: category, magento-2.1, product-images

I've looked at the following post and a few others, and the methods for constructing the image URL are failing for me:
[Getting full image url for products via REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93000/getting-full-image-url-for-products-via-rest-api)

How can I construct the full image URL paths for the images returned for a category and a product?

For a category the image information is provided in the custom_attributes array like the following:

```
{
   "attribute_code": "image",
   "value": "look01_index.jpg"
}
```

For a product's description the image URL I'm after looks like the following:

```
  "id": 3717,
  "media_type": "image",
  "label": null,
  "position": 1,
  "disabled": false,
  "types": [
    "image",
    "small_image",
    "thumbnail"
  ],
  "file": "/l/o/look01_index_1.jpg"
```

I've tried to make the path with `{IPADDRESS}/pub/media/catalog/product/{IMAGE FILE}` and this fails for both the product and category.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

For Categories:
{IP_ADDRESS}/pub/media/catalog/category/{FILE NAME}

For Products:
{IP_ADDRESS}/pub/media/catalog/product/{PATH IN DETAILS}

Learned the category path by by hovering over the image on the admin GUI.  For products, I believe I was trying to use the category file name in the product path.